# How do I unlock the banners?

Tags: might-and-magic-duel-of-champions

About half the banners in the profile area of the game are locked.

I've seen that some things are locked by acheivements or levels.

Is there a list somewhere of what I have to do for each banner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the banners are unlocked by completing specific [achievements](http://duelofchampions.gamepedia.com/Achievements):

**I am Necropolis**
 - (Win 30 ranked duels with Necropolis Decks)
**I am Inferno**
 - (Win 30 ranked duels with Inferno Decks)
**I am Haven**
 - (Win 30 ranked duels with Haven Decks)
**I am Stronghold**
 - (Win 30 ranked duels with Stronghold Decks)
**I am Sanctuary**
 - (Win 30 ranked duels with Sanctuary Decks)
**Necropolis' Chosen One**
 - (Win 20 ranked duels with the Necropolis Hero from the Herald of the Void expansion, [Adar-Malik](http://duelofchampions.gamepedia.com/Adar-Malik,_Caller_of_Doom))
**Inferno's Chosen One**
 - (Win 20 ranked duels with the Inferno Hero from the Herald of the Void expansion, [Dhamiria](http://duelofchampions.gamepedia.com/Dhamiria,_Caller_of_Madness))
**Haven's Chosen One**
 - (Win 20 ranked duels with the Haven Hero from the Herald of the Void expansion, [Alia](http://duelofchampions.gamepedia.com/Alia,_Caller_of_Faith))
**Stronghold's Chosen One**
 - (Win 20 ranked duels with the Stronghold Hero from the Herald of the Void expansion, [Zardoc](http://duelofchampions.gamepedia.com/Zardoc,_Caller_of_Valor))
**Sanctuary's Chosen One**
 - (Win 20 ranked duels with the Sanctuary Hero from the Herald of the Void expansion, [Noboru](http://duelofchampions.gamepedia.com/Noboru,_Caller_of_Twilight))

**Frozen Moment III**
 - (Own one of each Sanctuary card from the Forgotten Wars expansion)
**Bloodly Gaze III**
 -  (Own one of each Stronghold card from the Forgotten Wars expansion)
**Dead Horizon III**
 - (Own one of each Necropolis card from the Forgotten Wars expansion)
**Havenly Sight III**
 - (Own one of each Haven card from the Forgotten Wars expansion)
**Infernal Visions III**
 - (Own one of each Inferno card from the Forgotten Wars expansion)
**Forbidden Word I**
 - (Own one of each Academy card from the Forgotten Wars expansion)